# How to check if a docker image was pushed successfully from python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, cloud

I am using the "docker" library of python to push docker image to AWS ECR registry. This script runs in a scheduled manner. So I want to add an alerting step if the docker push fails. So how to check if the docker push failed or not?
This is my code:

```
import docker
docker_client_aws = docker.from_env()
docker_client_aws.login(username=ecr_username, password=ecr_password, registry=ecr_url)
image.tag(ecr_repo_name, tag='latest')
push_log = docker_client_aws.images.push(ecr_repo_name, tag='latest')
print(push_log)
```

Comment: Well, according to the API description, if the server raise an error, push will raise a  
`docker.errors.APIError` so maybe you could catch that and log something (or do whatever you want to alert you on fail) https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.push

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the comment, the library will raise an exception if anything goes wrong, as is standard in Python code. Assuming that's the whole script, the uncaught exception would reach the top level of the interpreter and it would print a stack trace and then exit with a non-0 return code so you can check via that.